# VB.net validating textbox input for integers crash

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, parsing, integer

I have a form in where users need to input integers to save to an xml when they press a button 
the issue lies that when the user does not put in valid input, it displays the error but still attempts to declare the variables for my function and then crashes - how do i stop this?

here's my code:

```
        If IsNumeric(txtLevel.Text) And IsNumeric(txtHealth.Text) Then
            MsgBox("choose a location to save in")
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHealth.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLevel.Text) Then
            MsgBox("you have not filled in all fields")
            Me.Close()
        Else MsgBox("please input number form")
        End If

        Dim strName As String = txtCharacter.Text
        Dim intLevel As Integer = txtLevel.Text
        Dim intHealth As Integer = txtHealth.Text
        Dim strStat As String = cmbStat.Text
```

Comment: You need to return or exit out of your validation method. Possibly move the validation to the textbox validation event.

Comment: `Return` or `Exit Sub/Function` to not reach the `Dims`. Probably the crash is due to trying to access the first disposed object. `txtCharacter`.

Comment: Where does it crash?  Nothing that you're showing here ought to have a problem, I don't think.  If you run in the debugger, it should stop at the line where the unhandled exception issues.

Comment: Wow! You only get one chance to do it right. How about just showing a message and letting the user fix the problem. Use Exit Sub or, even better, Return instead of Close.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using quite a few legacy features and you also have Option Strict turned off.

- IsNumeric should be replaced with Integer.TryParse: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse
- MsgBox should be replaced with MessageBox: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox
- For more information on option strict, I suggest you check out any of these resources:

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement
  - https://www.vblessons.com/lessons.html#/1/2
  - http://vb.net-informations.com/language/vb.net_option_strict.htm

With that being said, your code could look like this:

```vb
Dim strName As String = txtCharacter.Text
Dim strStat As String = cmbStat.Text
Dim intLevel, intHealth As Integer

' if either condition is true, close the form prematurely
If (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtLevel.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtHealth.Text)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("You have not filled in all fields.", "Invalid Form")
    Me.Close()
ElseIf (Not Integer.TryParse(txtLevel.Text, intLevel) OrElse Not Integer.TryParse(txtHealth.Text, intHealth)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please input number form.", "Invalid Form")
    Me.Close()
End If

' continue on with the code
```

Comment: thank you so much, this worked splendidly! is there any way string.isnullorwhitespace in a way that it activates when any string is nullorwhitespace not all of them?

Comment: @piqto you will need to break it down into two separate conditions. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Move your variable declaration inside your "If IsNumeric(txtLevel.Text) And IsNumeric(txtHealth.Text) Then" so its only going to try to assign them the value if both txtLevel and txtHealth are integers.

I would suggest you to change the code like so:

```
    'Checks if the textboxes are not empty
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHealth.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLevel.Text) Then
        'They are not empty, so the program checks if they are integers
        If IsNumeric(txtLevel.Text) And IsNumeric(txtHealth.Text) Then
            'The input is integer
            Dim strName As String = txtCharacter.Text
            Dim intLevel As Integer = txtLevel.Text
            Dim intHealth As Integer = txtHealth.Text
            Dim strStat As String = cmbStat.Text

            MsgBox("choose a location to save in")
        Else
            'The input is not integer
            MsgBox("Value is not an integer")
        End If
    Else
        'A textbox is empty
        MsgBox("you have not filled in all fields")
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: Use `Integer.TryParse(..)` instead of `IsNumeric(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `TryParse` to be sure of integer value without error :

```
Dim intLevel As Integer 
Dim intHealth As Integer 

If (Integer.TryParse(txtLevel.Text, intLevel)) And (Integer.TryParse(txtHealth.Text, intHealth)) Then
                MsgBox("choose a location to save in")
ElseIf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHealth.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLevel.Text) Then
                MsgBox("you have not filled in all fields")
                Me.Close()
Else MsgBox("please input number form")
End If

Dim strName As String = txtCharacter.Text
Dim strStat As String = cmbStat.Text
```

find more about it on : [Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I don't think this resolves "but still attempts to declare the variables for my function and then crashes - how do i stop this?"

Comment: can you show the code and the error ? if so do Edit on your post

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm just commenting that I don't think your code stops execution when a validation failure occurs, so the OPs issue could still occur.

Comment: `Return` after each `If`.